# Rails console error - savon gem

Tags: web-services, savon, rails-console

i try this comand on rails console:

`client = Savon.client("http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL")`

but this erros appears:

`TypeError: can't convert String into Hash`

and i already have add 'savon' gem to my gemfile and the version of savon is 2.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

Another man has answered this in a twin question. Here's a link to his answer and I can confirm that his answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14344886/133257

```
client = Savon.client(:wsdl => "http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL")
```